T-SNE on OCTMNIST gives bad results no matter the parameters
I am trying to implement T-SNE on OCTMNIST. No matter how I try to change the parameters however I never get a good result. This is my code
tsne_ft = TSNE(
    n_components=2,           # Dimensionality of embedding
    perplexity=40,            # Adjust based on dataset size
    learning_rate=300,        # Experiment with values from 10 to 1000
    max_iter=1500,              # Increase for better optimization
    init='pca',               # Try 'pca' for better initialization
    random_state=42           # Ensure reproducibility
)

run for a 10k random balanced sample gives me the following graph:

I have seen however papers that get a much better output graph

Although I get that the whole of OCTMNIST is not balanced, as I have it, shouldn't it still be able to perform a bit better? I have tried removing and adding PCA initialization, adjusting learning rate, exageration, perplexity, max_iter but nothing seems to work. Any ideas would be invaluable!

This could be as simple as your data not really possessing strong cluster structure. It is not secret or surprising that people choose examples for their papers or texts which show their (favourite) method working well. I've often been stimulated by multivariate texts to try a method on some data, only to discover that my data were a messy continuum, which on reflection was not really a discovery, but expected all along.

Some are voting to close this because it seems like a request for code and such requests are off topic.  I voted to leave it open, since it seems the main question is not code. But you might want to edit the question to stress that.

There are plenty of problems with t-SNE and UMAP, which may be relevant here. But we cannot answer this unless if we don't even know if you should find structure in the data.
